# 2 divs in horizontal space

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="msg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    <div id="img"><div id="content"></div></div>
</div>

#container{
    position:absolute;
    width:182px;
    height:60px;
}
#msg{
    width:95px;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    display: table; 
    background:#666;
}
#msg p{
    font-size:13px;
    color:#eee;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;   
}
#img{
    width:87px;
    height:60px;
    float:right;
    background:#333;
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    width:80px;
    height:45px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

I want when div img gets hidden (display:none) that div msg gets 100% width of the parent. Butt he text needs to stay centered.

http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/801/

Comment: That's  what it does.. http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/802/

Comment: you're question doesn't make sense...as stated by @Adelphia, you're asking a question to achieve something you are already achieving

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can achieve what you want with [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). No need for crazy display:table...

Comment: @gtramontina display:table if well used here is efficient and covers many more browser than flexbox does :) http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/804/

Comment: Yes, but when img gets hidden, msg width needs to stay as the width of the parent container (width:182px). I said in my initial post: 

I want when div img gets hidden (display:none) that div msg gets 100% width of the parent.

Comment: @GCyrillus I do agree with that, although I'm getting tired of supporting the old web; having to add meaningless `divs` is just nonsense. Embrace the new web with evergreen browsers and be happy. -- sorry for the rant :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display:table; is a good idea but those rule should be dispatch to main container and its two childs in order to be efficient with your goal.

Hover the demo to hide `#img` and see `#msg` filling whole width of `#container`:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ELKQg/804/)**

```
#container {
    display:table;
    width:182px;
    height:60px;
}
#msg {
    width:95px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#666;
    text-align: center;
}
#msg p {
    font-size:13px;
    color:#eee;
}
#img {
    width:87px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: table-cell;
    background:#333;
}
#container:hover #img {
    display:none;
}
#content {
    width:80px;
    height:45px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have something other than table on parent container?

Comment: display:flex; but then it can be wised to keep display:table as a fallback. anyhow, to set vertical-align, float is not to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a change in the message width might do the job:

```
$("#msg").on('click', function(){
    $("#img").css('display', 'none');
    $("#msg").css('width', '100%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is possible with jquery.I have added the script that will solve this issue.
For testing i have added display:none; in #img id.

```
<style type="text/css" >
#container{
    position:absolute;
    width:182px;
    height:60px;
}
#msg{
    width:95px;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    display: table; 
    background:#666;
}
#msg p{
    font-size:13px;
    color:#eee;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;   
}
#img{
    width:87px;
    height:60px;
    float:right;
    background:#333;
    display:none;
}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    width:80px;
    height:45px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.w100{
    width:100% !important;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="msg"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
    <div id="img"><div id="content"></div></div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" >
if ($('#img').css('display') == 'none') {
    $( "#msg" ).addClass( "w100" );
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can add additional markup if neccesarry, I just wish if this could be done with pure css.

Comment: hi @Toniq i have posted another solution that will work without jquery.please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that will work without jquery but you need to change the  structure.

```
<style type="text/css" >
#container{
    position:absolute;
    width:182px;
    height:60px;
}
#msg{
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    display: table; 
    background:#666;
}
#msg p{
    font-size:13px;
    color:#eee;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;   
}
#img{
    width:87px;
    height:60px;
    float:right;
    background:#333;
    display:none;

}
#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    width:80px;
    height:45px;
    background:#ccc;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="msg">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <div id="img"><div id="content"></div></div>
    </div>

</div>
```